# how can I get list of email in gmail api with title and sender of email?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I have tried using 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages

but only get id and threadId as a response.

I want to display list of email with title and from email. Is there an api exist to get info or any way I can get it?

Comment: @DalmTo Can you give a way for it ?

Answer (score 0):

The [user messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) method only returns a message list of message id and thread id. This is a limitation in the API itself and there is nothing you can do to change that.  Its a free api and we are bound by the limitations of google.

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "16d1f7849145662a",
   "threadId": "16d1f55457d4e145"
  },
  {
   "id": "16d1f69d541016ee",
   "threadId": "16d1f55457d4e145"
  },
```

In order to get additional information about the message you need to do a [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) on each message.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id
```

Sorry its the only way its a lot of gets.

## batching

You can try the batching endpoing [batch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)  You're limited to 100 calls in a single batch request. If you need to make more calls than that, use multiple batch requests.

## postman headers

> Content-Type multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz; type=application/http
>
> Authorization Bearer ya29.GluBB7_cEfLMThXKuxR_9g8YyjSTLwBHRHdPtiYXwDABKQlrbxEyFqSFsnFYTs5b54W7
>
> Accept-Encoding application/gzip

## postman body

```
--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d24956228a98c4
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d24956228a98c4
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

## SMTP

beyond that you can go though the [smtp server directly](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp?hl=zh-TW).  This will require a programming language which can handle direct calls to a mail server.

Comment: @DalmTo If i want to display list as like we got in gmail, so for each message I have to make an request. It will increasing load on server.

Comment: Yup it will but you should have loads of quota and you can buffer the list once you have an email it shouldn't change other than maybe getting a thread id.   You could try and play around with the batch endpoint.   You can make more then one request in one request.

Comment: @DalmTo In gmail case, to fetch list along with title and sender, how batch request can be modified?

Comment: @Sa1 there is very little documentation on batching.  You will need to check the original documentation and build it out from that. If you are using a client library they they all support batching and probably have an option for that that will be easier for you to use.  I edited the raw batch request a bit it should be something like that.

Comment: Would the -1 please comment as to the reason for the -1 so that i can improve the answer and make it more clear for you to understand.  This is all directly out of the documentation.

Comment: @DalmTo batch endpoint batch/farm/v1 HTTP/1.1 contains farm.farm is used for what in gmail listing api?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail API is designed in such a way, that

1. you need to obtain the IDs of all emails of interest (you can use the search parameter `q` to filter the results) with `GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages` - as you already did
2. you need to retrieve each of the messages separately by their ID with `GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id`

If you write a code in a language of your choice you can automatize this process with loops.

Sample how to do it with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/):

```
function myFunction() {
  var myMessages=Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me",{'maxResults': 5 }).messages;
  Logger.log(myMessages);
  for(var i=0;i<myMessages.length;i++){
    var id=myMessages[i].id;
    Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', id).payload.headers.forEach(function(e){
      if(e.name=="Subject"||e.name=="From"){
        Logger.log(e.name+": "+e.value)
      }
     }
    );
  }
}
```